# How can I send commands to Chrome extension via a local python application?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I've been trying to figure out a way to send commands to a chrome extension via python. My goal is to automate browser functions such as opening a new tab or reloading a page remotely, but on the same computer. What would be the best/simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

look at [python web browser module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/webbrowser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a tool selenium, you only need add a driver for your web browser.

Comment: Please elaborate - "use tool named X" is not much of an answer at all.